# Pasar una funcion de seleccion jquery a Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Investigando un poco de jquery, he encontrado esta función:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function () {
    let element = $(this)[0]
    let search = $(element).attr('dat')
    console.log(element)
})
```

Estoy aprendiendo javascript - aun no sé mucho, me he dado cuenta que con esa función guardo el elemento seleccionado, quisiera saber como podría pasar la función de arriba a javascript, y también de ser posible explicarme que está haciendo el `this` y el `[0]`, eh visto el `this` muy seguido, pero me cuesta entenderlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por parte por parte

- jQuery es una librería para JavaScript
- Para que jQuery pueda hacer la manipulación de elementos normalmente envuelve los objetos nativos.
- Para envolver los objetos hace uso de una función llamada `$()` que es equivalente a `jQuery()`.  El símbolo `$` no tiene nada de especial, es un identificador, podría haber sido llamado `a`, `x`, etc.
- Entonces `$(document)` significa que toma el elemento `document` que es la parte visible de la ventana y lo envuelve.  No necesita equivalente, se puede usar `document` directamente.
- `.on('click', '.class', function() { ... })` es la forma en que jQuery agrega un manejador de eventos, en este caso clic de cualquier parte del documento.
- El equivalente normalmente sería `.addEventListener('click', function(event) { ... })`.  Donde `event` es un parámetro que el navegador nos proveerá con información sobre el evento. Puedes ponerle cualquier nombre.
- Hay un detalle en el segundo parámetro. `'.class'` es un selector, cuando le pasas ese parámetro signficia que solo debería disparar el manejador de eventos cuando el elemento encaja con el filtro.  En este caso que tenga una clase llamada `class`
- En este caso específico, `this` dentro de `on()` hace referencia al elemento que hizo match con el selector y que dispararó el evento.  El valor de `this` puede variar dependiendo de como se realizó la invocación.
- `$(this)` es otra vez para convertirlo en un objeto jQuery pero como pueden haber sido múltiples elementos los que fueron seleccionados, usan `[0]` para elegir el primero.  Esto es la sintaxis para arreglos normal de JavaScript.

Entonces el equivalente en JavaScript puro sería:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let element = event.target;

    if (element.classList.contains('class')) {
        let search = element.getAttribute('dat');
        console.log(element); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo, me ayudaste a entender muy bien, de casualidad tienes alguna pagina o enlace donde aprendiste el uso del this?

Comment: La mejor documentación que conozco para todo lo que tiene que ver con JavaScript, HTML y CSS es MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), los mismos de Firefox. `this` es algo especial en JavaScript pero aquí un punto de partida: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this